# Is current Ubuntu Core also meant for the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+?

Tags: raspberrypi

I am having trouble understanding whether or not current Ubuntu versions include the CM3+.

https://ubuntu.com/download/iot has the download for the regular RPi models.

> Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi
>
> Get the power, ease and flexibility of Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 2, 3 or 4.

There is also a section for Compute Module v3 here https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-compute-module-3

Which of the available images will work on the CM3+? Or is it not supported yet?